# Preventing masked url redirect from outside

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, url, redirection

We have a problem that someone trying to do masked url redirection for our e-commerce. How can we deny/abort? Using IIS or Windows Server.

Main Domain:   ecommerce.com

Masked Domain:  myshop.com -> opening ecommerce.com // We want to deny all masked/unmasked redirection

But we didn't do this redirection and we don't want outside domains like this. If there is a solution in DNS side that will be great too.

Answer (score 1):

A *redirection* is a concept of the HTTP protocol ([RFC 9110, 15.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#section-15.4)), where the server tells the client (browser) that the content is somewhere else, and the browser automatically opens the URL given in the `Location` header ([10.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#section-10.2.2)). The server at the destination URL is not aware that this redirection ever happened, as it does not even leave a `Referer` request header ([10.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#section-10.1.3)) as clicking a link would.

TL;DR: HTTP redirection cannot be detected or blocked on the destination side.

Comment: Yay! This was the first time I had the chance to reference the fresh _HTTP Semantics_ **Internet Standard** ([RFC 9110](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110)) instead of the _Proposed Standard_, RFC 7230-7235.